# Terraform make variable nullable based on other variable value

Tags: terraform, okta, terragrunt

I'm working with Okta provider and I want to implement `app_oauth`. There is an attribute like `redirect_uris` ([documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/okta/okta/3.41.0/docs/resources/app_oauth#redirect_uris)) and this attrobute is required for all application types except `service`. I was trying to solve this like that in my `vars.tf`:

```
variable "type" {
  description = "Application Type"
  type        = string
  nullable    = false
}

variable "redirect_uris" {
  description = "Application Grant Types"
  type        = list(string)
  nullable    = var.type == "service" ? true : false
}
```

Unfortunately while running `terragrunt plan` I get:

```
 Error: Variables not allowed
│ 
│   on vars.tf line 23, in variable "redirect_uris":
│   23:   nullable    = var.type == "service" ? true : false
│ 
│ Variables may not be used here.
╵

╷
│ Error: Unsuitable value type
│ 
│   on vars.tf line 23, in variable "redirect_uris":
│   23:   nullable    = var.type == "service" ? true : false
│ 
│ Unsuitable value: value must be known
```

Can somebody give me any tips how to deal with that?

EDIT: working solution

```
resource "okta_app_oauth" "app" {
  label          = var.label
  type           = var.type
  grant_types    = var.grant_types
  redirect_uris  = var.type != "service" ? var.redirect_uris : null
  response_types = var.response_types
}
```

Comment: That cannot work. Can you add the resource you mention to the question?

Comment: @MarkoE is under `documentation` link

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce anything from a link, rather a code block. Additionally, the link leads to an older version of the Okta provider. Which version are you using?

Comment: Yes, that's true, I'm using 3.41 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have not posted a reproducible code block, I think you could achieve what you want by doing the following:

```
redirect_uris = var.type != "service" ? var.redirect_uris : null
```

Comment: I eddited question and added code block, but your solution is working, thanks!

Comment: Ah, so I didn't read the docs properly, so fixed the answer.